# Vue js - create and subscribe events in two different components using rxjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs

I would to pass data from one component to another which are individual by generating an event. So i planned to use `rxjs`. Here i created simple observable on clicking on the button in one component

```
    Observable.create((observer) => {
     observer.next('hello')
    })
```

I am trying to subscribe this observable in another component, how can i do that? Or is there any other way to create observable generated by one component and use it in another component.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an observer out of scope of a component and import for subscription.

```
export const observer = Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next('hello');
});

import observer from './observer';
created() {
  observer.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}

outputs ==> 'Hello'
```

***// For watching and subscribing to parent data***

```
props: {
  parentData: {
   type: 'object',
   required: true      
  }  
},
watch: {
  parentData(updatedProps) {
     console.log('Props Updated'. updatedProps);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I can create a global file, but how can I pass the data from one component. Like u r sending 'hello' from global file, I need to pass the 'hello' from one component and want to catch that data in another component. How can I do that?

Comment: In order to do that, You can use inbuilt watch methods and watch variables from props

Comment: Hey i have been thinking about this, it doesnt solve my problem because there is a props which you defined parentData right? it wont even there in my case because, the components are individual component 1 is not a parent of component 2. so there will not be any props.

Comment: I will explain my question in simple words, i would like to generate value or event after clicked on button in component 1 and need to catch that value or event in component 2. Component 1 and component 2 are not dependent on each other. We can achieve this using EventBus in vue, but i would like to see using observable. If there is any thing please let me know. thanks.

Comment: I had been there, Two components cannot communicate bidirectionally without dependent on each other, Where eventBus can be used as single flow.

I had used a reducer to pass the value and get it back from there using a getter. wish there could be a two way data flow design pattern between components.

You can use Subject concept of rxjs. But the variable or subject should be out of the scope of a component. like in a separate file.

hope it helps,thankyou